# decode mysqlbinlog in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, decoding, logfiles

MySQL saves all changes to the database in a binary file called binary log.
MySQL provides a decoder called mysqlbinlog to decode these files. I thought if I wanted to parse this log file directly from an application then I need to find a way to decode it myself using C# for instance.

I know if I had the privilege I could use SHOW BINLOG EVENTS. However, parsing the file would be a better solution for me.

Has any of you done that before? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look into the [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/sources/doxygen/mysql-5.1/mysqlbinlog_8cc-source.html)-tool code might be useful. Additionally, the dependencies of that tool are available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/sources/doxygen/mysql-5.1/mysqlbinlog_8cc.html)

Comment: I'am not a C guru but I'll figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: *g* It's C++ ;) Thus, not tooo far away from c#

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not a C++ expert and would take considerably long for me to figure out the code suggested by tuergeist, I have choosen another approach.

Since mysqlbinlog is already provided why not use it?

- I could use the binary-log index to get all log files
- Pass the filenames to a method using ProcessStartInfo to read the output of mysqlbinlog
- The output then could be parsed to an array for instance.

I haven't tested it yet, but I'm working on it...

Comment: Were you successful in this approach?