# Reading MySql binlog

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqlbinlog

I don't agree that this question was answered effectively: [decode mysqlbinlog in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460471/decode-mysqlbinlog-in-c-sharp).

I have, what I think is the same question: I want to read the MySql binlogs from within a c# application, but do not know the format of the file. How can I properly parse these files' data?

Comment: the problem isn't format knowledge. You can get it from the source code. The problem is the format may change any time as nobody promised it will persist. I'd use mysqlbinlog to parse it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Eventually, I specifically want to know how to parse the binlog myself without using an outside utility. Do you know where, exactly, the format/s are or how I can find them? Sorry... I don't know how to access the (presumably, MySql) source code. 

For the meanwhile, your suggestion might work for getting my application started - if there is a way to use the mysqlbinlog utility from within c#. Is this possible? If so, do you know how? Thank you

Comment: start with ./client/mysqlbinlog.cc . The format should be straightforward. My C# knowledge is next to zero, I'd guess there must be something like exec() to call external program

Answer (score 3):

First, what I learned:

1. Most of the source code files for MySql are installed along with the assemblies and generally located in [basedir]\include. For example, a typical install would place the files in Program Files\MySql\MySql 5.6\include.
2. mysqlbin.cc was NOT in that folder. However, I was easily able to get the file by doing a quick Google search. The file can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/mg-common-utils/source/browse/trunk/myreplicator/src/mysqlbinlog.cc?r=4 . It is well documented and easy to read.

Second, my solution:

As akuzminsky pointed out, the format of MySql's binlog is subject to change. However, the format returned from the mysqlbinlog.exe utility is consistent. This application is typically included in a MySql install and should be located in [basedir]\bin. I now run this application from within a c# Console Application and parse the results. I used the following steps to accomplish this:

1. Enabled binlogging on the MySql server from within the options file. In MySql Workbench, check 'log-bin' under the logging tab. Or, type 'log-bin=' in the settings file (often located in [basedir]. Might be called 'my.ini' or 'my.cnf' or something else. Generally, with .cnf or .ini extension). A filename is not required. When one is not specified, MySql will automatically create filenames for the logs. However, review MySql documentation on possible issues with this.
2. From within my client application, I query the server to get the path of each binary log (there could be many). To do this:

   ```
   query show global variables like 'datadir' //returns the data directory.
   query show binary logs //returns the filename of each binary log, along with its file size (helpful for reading).
   ```

   - Parsing these together gets the path for each binary log.
3. Since mysqlbinlog.exe is located in [basedir]\bin, I query the server to get the path of the base directory:

   ```
   query show global variables like 'basedir'
   ```

   Then, I parse the result with '\bin\mysqlbinlog.exe'
4. I use the Process class to create a new process, execute each binary log using mysqlbinlog.exe, and read each files results into a string variable:

   ```
   private static string GetLogTexts(Liststring> logfilenames)
   {
       List<string> _logtexts = new List<string>();
       string _basedir = GetBaseDir();
       foreach(string logfilename in logfilenames)
       {
           Process proc = new Process();
           proc.StartInfo.FileName = _basedir + "\\bin\\mysqlbinlog";
           proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\"", logfile);
           proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
           proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
           proc.Start();
           _logtexts.Add(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
       }
       return _logtexts;
   }
   private static string GetBaseDir()
   {
       string path = "";
       using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(RemoteServerConnectionString))
       {
           conn.Open();
           using (MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("show global variables like 'basedir'", conn))
           {
               using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
               {
                   while (reader.Read())
                   {
                       path = reader.GetString(1);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       return path;
   }
   ```
5. Finally, I parse the results using my own logic (specific for what I am looking for). The results are very easy to read: mysqlbinlog uses regular line breaks and statements are terminated by a delimiter, which is defined prior to the statement (as usual, there can be multiple delimiters).

I hope this helps someone!